# Customize Button Appearance

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I've set up a button in my activity. Current code:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSkills"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:onClick="buttonSkillsOnClick"
    android:text="@string/skills"
    android:textColor="#32c87d"
    android:textSize="22sp" />
```

It currently has a white background to it. I would like the background to be transparent so that the user can only see the text.
When the user clicks the button, I just want a green border to appear around the button with no background.

I was wondering if this can be done with xml only?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please read the following on How to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the constructive criticism

Comment: No problem. One thing also to consider is your title. The title should frame the question in clear terms and avoid using tags appended to the front of the title. I rack up a bounty in rep points every day just for making those kinds of edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make a drawable for when the item is selected, then apply that as the background. So in short, yes it is possible to do it with only xml, but you will need to make an additional file.

Something similar to this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected" /> <!-- pressed -->
  <item android:state_focused="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/button_focus" /> <!-- focused -->
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_nothing" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

button_selected.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="ractangle">

    <solid android:color="#00FF00"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: How would you reference @drawable/button_nothing from inside drawable?

Comment: You need to make that file. That's where you would create the visual style for your button.

Comment: I added some example of what that could look like. Keep in mind that I just freehanded this, so it may need some debugging.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Is there any way that I can draw a rectangle outline without filling it?

Comment: Nevermind, I just used stroke instead of solid. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. All you need to do is assign a State List drawable as a background to the button. The state list drawable inturn contains references to Shape Drawable.

Read all about it here (Shape Drawable and State List topic): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

Make an xml file in drawable folder and paste this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item android:state_pressed="true" >
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="10dip" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#fff" />
         <gradient  android:angle="-90"  android:startColor="@color/primary" android:endColor="@color/primary_dark"  />
     </shape>
 </item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="10dip" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#fff" />
         <solid  android:color="#FF7300"/>       
     </shape>
 </item>    
 <item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="10dip" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#fff" />
         <gradient  android:angle="-90"  android:startColor="@color/primary" android:endColor="@color/primary" />
     </shape>
 </item>
</selector>
```

now set the background of a button like

```
android:background="@drawable/yourxml"
```

Comment: How do you access @color/primary from drawable?

Comment: Anyways, I got it to work already. Thanks to all for the help!